# How to read data from excel using code module in Ranorex?

Tags: ranorex

I want to read two columns of data from Excel sheet and I should assign that data to code module variable..please tell me how to write code in c# in ranorex?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the user guide [Lesson 3: Data-Driven Testing](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html). This lesson explains how to create variables in recording modules. The Section [Combining Variables with Test Data](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-3-data-driven-testing.html) covers the part on how to connect those variables with data e.g. from an Excel file.

Since you want to connect data with a code module instead of a recording module, have a look at Lesson 7: Code Modules, section [Using Variables with Code Modules](http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/lesson-7-code-modules.html). It covers how to create variables in code modules. These can then be connect just like variables from recording modules, as covered in lesson 3.